# Search Form not working on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I am having problems with the search form on wordpress. When i try and search any term at all it gives me the "Sorry, no posts match your query" response (I have "Search Everything" plugin installed too). I am using a child theme. so I tried to change the code in the child search.php (copied it to the child) and also created a searchform.php in the child. Here is the code from both of those that I am currently using:

SEARCH.PHP:

```
> <?php
/**
 * Search Template
 *
 * The search template is used to display search results from the native WordPress search.
 *
 * If no search results are found, the user is assisted in refining their search query in
 * an attempt to produce an appropriate search results set for the user's search query.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

 get_header();
 global $woo_options;
?>      
    <!-- #content Starts -->
    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="col-full">

        <div id="main-sidebar-container">    

            <!-- #main Starts -->
            <?php woo_main_before(); ?>
            <section id="main" class="col-left">

                <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', '' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => get_query_var('s')) );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
?>
<?php var_dump($the_query) ?>
            </section><!-- /#main -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- /#main-sidebar-container -->         

        <?php get_sidebar( 'alt' ); ?>       

    </div><!-- /#content -->
    <?php woo_content_after(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

SEARCHFORM.PHP (I got from the twenty twelve theme):

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
    </form>
```

I have tried different code for the searchform.php too such as:

```
  <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
        <label class="hidden" for="s"><?php _e('Search:'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="GO" />
    </form>
```

and

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

But still nothing. When it searches, this is what i get in the url:

```
http://www.energyhealing.directory/?s=energy&submit=Search
```

and on the page for that URL it displays:

Search Results for: energy << the title for it

Listed in
Continue Reading << thats a link to nowhere, just comes back to the same page

If someone could just explain to me where I have gone wrong and why, that would be amazing?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give. I look forward to hearing back from you!

Aww ok I see how to post in the question now:

Here is the code from the search.php which just returns the blank page:

```
  <?php
/**
 * Search Template
 *
 * The search template is used to display search results from the native WordPress search.
 *
 * If no search results are found, the user is assisted in refining their search query in
 * an attempt to produce an appropriate search results set for the user's search query.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

 get_header();
 global $woo_options;
?>      
    <!-- #content Starts -->
    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="col-full">

        <div id="main-sidebar-container">    

            <!-- #main Starts -->
            <?php woo_main_before(); ?>
            <section id="main" class="col-left">

                <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', '' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => get_query_var('s')) );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
?>
            </section><!-- /#main -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- /#main-sidebar-container -->         

        <?php get_sidebar( 'alt' ); ?>       

    </div><!-- /#content -->
    <?php woo_content_after(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The code from your search.php seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED (for search.php):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):?> 
        <ul>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

            <li><?php the_title();?></li>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
 <?php endif;?>
```

I think the searchform.php is ok, but I don't see a loop anywhere in your search.php

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => get_query_var('s')) );


// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

You need this query to create a loop based on the search.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for you comment! I tried to add the code you provided, but now it just prints this:

$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => get_query_var('s')) );


// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

Comment: Sorry, prints that in the search form area when i search for a term? Thanks again!

Comment: You need to wrap that in PHP tags.

Comment: Could fit all the code in, but i tried it:

             <header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', '' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
   </header><!-- .page-header -->

<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => get_query_var('s')) );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
?>
            </section><!-- /#main -->

Comment: but i just get a blank screen now when i search for something and "Search Results for: energy". Underneath that is blank though

Comment: can you post your code in the question? The formatting here is terrible

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that, how can i post the code without it messing up like that?

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of `$the_query` ?

Comment: Im not sure what a var_dump is, but ive added the search.php code to the end of the original post above. Thanks again!

Comment: Try adding this `var_dump($the_query)` after you call WP_Query. Then add the result to the question

Comment: Ok i tried adding the var_dump (tried within the WP_Query but it just gave me a blank white page, and then tried just after the WP_Query and got "NULL" come up where the listings should be on that page. I have added that code i changed to the question above in replace of the search.php i added before

Comment: @CleausKriyaYogiNeverson-Brow, I edited my answer to make it simpler

Comment: What do you mean you edited your answer to make it simpler? Do you know why the code I am using isn't working? What else shall i try?

Comment: I was just making the answer as simple as I could, because maybe your search plugin had a problem with the custom query. Have you tried desactivating the plugin?

Comment: Oh ok sorry. Yes i tried deactivating all of them and taking away any custom code i had added, but the same thing happened.

Comment: Ok, where's the file located?

Comment: In my child theme, with the searchform.php as well